# Is the iPhone 8 Plus case compatible with iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: case, iphone

I am wondering if the new iPhone 8 Plus is case compatible with the iPhone 7 Plus, meaning that I can buy an iPhone 7 Plus case today and would be able to use with my new iPhone 8 Plus once I receive it?

The reason for my question is that I cannot find the physical dimension of these models on apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that the iPhone 8 Plus is case compatible to the iPhone 7 Plus. I was checking the one of the iPhone 7 Plus cases and on apple.com. It stated that it is good for both of these models.

Also there is the [phone comparison page](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) on apple.com where the dimensions are listed.